# chartjs resizing very quickly (flickering) on mouseover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I have a chart in a bootstrap-based page and I'm trying to resize it when the page gets resized, to follow the changes of the responsive design. So I have this piece of code:

```
function redrawChart() {
    var w = $("#chart_container").width();
    var c = document.getElementById("chart_canvas");
    c.width = w;
    c.height = w/2;
    $("#chart_canvas").css("width", w);
    $("#chart_canvas").css("height", w/2);

    var chart_canvas = document.getElementById("chart_canvas").getContext("2d");
    var line_chart= new Chart(chart_canvas).Line(data, options);
};

redrawChart();

var resizeTimer; 

$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(redrawChart, 250);
});
```

So redrawChart is called once when the page is loaded and then with every page resize.

Symptoms: when the page is loaded, everything works perfectly as long as it's not resized. After a resize, the chart flickers, gets resized very quickly when the mouse is hovering over it.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: If I only resize it horizontally then the flickering is only horizontal too. I hope I am making myself clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to destroy the chart before you recreate it on the same canvas. So you can edit your redraw like so:

```
 //declare outside so it can be resued and checked
 var line_chart;

function redrawChart() {
    //if we already have a chart destroy it then carry on as normal
    if(line_chart)
    {
            line_chart.destroy();
    }
    var w = $("#chart_container").width();
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    c.width = w;
    c.height = w/2;
    $("#chart_canvas").css("width", w);
    $("#chart_canvas").css("height", w/2);

    var chart_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    line_chart= new Chart(chart_canvas).Bar(barChartData);
};
```

here is a fiddle so you can actually re-size the run window to see it working http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/4apqqjL0/

and a snippet it that's your fancy

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function () {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
};

var barChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
    }, {
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
    }, {
        fillColor: "rgba(15,18,20,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(15,18,20,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(15,18,20,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(15,18,20,1)",
        data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
    }]

}


 var line_chart;

function redrawChart() {
    if(line_chart)
    {
            line_chart.destroy();
    }
    var w = $("#chart_container").width();
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    c.width = w;
    c.height = w/2;
    $("#chart_canvas").css("width", w);
    $("#chart_canvas").css("height", w/2);

    var chart_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    line_chart= new Chart(chart_canvas).Bar(barChartData);
};

redrawChart();

var resizeTimer; 

$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(redrawChart, 250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart_container"style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to destroy the chart previous data. Bellow example for Ajax request. if you use destroy you should be use canvas height and width otherwise it your graph size going to reduce in every response.

```
$("#search_date").on('change', function(){
 if(window.myBar!=null){
     window.myBar.destroy();
   }
  var date = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
     url: "test/test",
     type: "post",
     data: {
       searchDate:date
     },
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(response){

       var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

       var barChartData = {

         labels : response.namedata,
         datasets : [
           {
             fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
             strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
             highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
             highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
             data :  response.countdata
           }
         ]

       }

       var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
       ctx.canvas.width = 200;
       ctx.canvas.height = 200;
       window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
         responsive : true
       });

     }

   })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles to the parent element of the canvas:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```