# How to stop React rerenders when mouse cursor is changed dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that I need to change the cursor type based on the location of the mouse cursor.

The mouse cursor is dynamically set on the style of the div.

`<div style={{cursor:cursor}}>`

The type is stored in

`const [cursor,SetCursor]=useState('default');`

I'm changing the cursor type with onHover event.  When onHover event is triggered, mouse screen location is checked and if the mouse is in a specific zone, I run

`SetCursor('crosshair')`

It is working as expected, except that every time the cursor type is changed, the screen rerenders.
How can I prevent the screen render when the cursor type changes?

additional explanation:

I change the cursor dynamically because I don't have a DIV to target. There is a box annotation drawn on a chart.js chart. I'm using mouse screen location to target when the pointer is inside and when the pointer is outside the box. I use the events from chartJS to change the cursor type. My question is how can I change the cursor type dynamically without rerendering in React

Comment: <div style={{cursor:cursor}}> is parent tag?

Comment: Any state change is going to trigger a re-render.  Taking a step back, is this functionality even necessary?  Why not specify the cursor with CSS?

Comment: I change the cursor dynamically because I don't have a DIV to target.
There is a box annotation drawn on a chart.js chart.  I'm using mouse screen location to target when the pointer is inside and when the pointer is outside the box.   I use the events from chartJS to change the cursor type.  My question is how can I change the cursor type dynamically without rerender in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution by drawing 3 vertically spaced transparent divs over the annotation box with absolute positioning. Each of the 3 divs has a cursor type of 'e-resize', 'move', 'w-resize'.

Thanks for suggesting to use CSS.  This method seems more elegant than my first attempt.  Now when I go over the annotation box, the cursor type changes without rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said in the comments, why not use css?

```css
.my-class:hover {
   cursor: pointer
}
```

If you wanted to do have the css be dynamically applied to certain classes, you could use a system like [MUI's sx prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/), which would allow you to apply the style in your Javascript like:

```
<Box // wrapper around div
  sx={{
    "&:hover": {cursor: "pointer"}
  }} 
>
{...}
</Box>
```

Although if you do it the way you're currently doing it, why is the render causing problems? Updating state and rerendering often is usually peeformant and quite common with React.

Comment: render doesn't cause a problem, it just doesn't look good.  The render is unnecessary when cursor type changes.

Comment: what doesn't look good? Is the rerender causing a flicker or something?

Regardless, using CSS is probably the way to go.

Comment: I need to change the cursor type only when in specific mouse coordinates.  I don't think I can use CSS.

Comment: Is it when you're hovering over specific elements? What's your use case?

Comment: the annotation box is displayed over a chart.  When the mouse cursor is inside the annotation box, the user can press the left mouse button and resize the box. I'm saving the cursor type in a state variable.  When inside the box, I'm changing the mouse cursor by SetCursor.  This state change rerenders the chart.  I want to prevent rerender when the mouse cursor is changed.

Comment: Ah, using a canvas for it? Anyhow, earlier you said "render doesn't cause a problem, it just doesn't look good", what doesn't look good about it? Is it flickering or soemthing?

Comment: yes as I move in and out of the annotation box, chartJS rerenders.  It looks terrible.  This use case may be a limitation with React I didn't expect.

Comment: What exactly looks terrible? It flickers? Shifts size? What?

Comment: chart flickers and renders over and over as the mouse pointer is moved in and out of the annotation box.  As is my implementation is unusable although it is working as expected.

Comment: It looks like you may need to destroy the chart before rendering it on the same canvas, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579424/954986 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630994/954986

Answer (score 0):

When you set a state in react app it is going to be re render you can't prevent that.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was hoping for a workaround where I could shut off rerender when the cursor dynamically changes.